# Qt QAxObject - Find Documentation for Excell API/SDK on querySubObject and Cell Properties

Tags: excel, qt, qaxobject

I need to integrate my Qt Application with MS Excel, I have created a class that can do the job so well but I have limited knowledge of the variables to include when dealing with the worksheet (querySubObject) and Cell Properties such as borders (Bottom Border, Top Border, Bottom Double border,etc), as well as writing images, chats, etc into the spreadsheet, headers and footers(this very important). I have searched the internet in vain. Can someone point to me how I can access these attributes so I can make my exports look elegant to the final user? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a link [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/excel/object-model) which lists all the Ms Excel Objects, methods as well as enumerations that we need in Qt. They are designed for VBA but luckily enough they are understandable and well explained by Microsoft